# Connection to server at port 5436 failed running on docker

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I am trying to install pgAdmin4 in my windows machine. I am getting error message of `connection to server failed`.
[image]

I found a similar kind of issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109494/unable-to-connect-to-server-pgadmin-4) but the solution doesn't work. I have been struggling with the issue and didn't found any working solution. Earlier, I have PostgreSql 15 version installed but the 15 version was not compatible with yii2 project of mine. So, I uninstalled the PostgreSQL 15 version and reinstalled PostgreSQL 13. After reinstalling I start getting this error.

I tried to restart the services of postgresql from `Task Manager -> Services` but didn't worked.

Can anyone suggest me what I am doing wrong or what can I do get this fixed.

Many Thanks.

Comment: By mistake I put wrong port in the title. Updated it to correct one.

Comment: I am not  sure what to do. But it's a common error. it's documented in manual. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html#CLIENT-CONNECTION-PROBLEMS You can google around. there is also some youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=psql%3A+could+not+connect+to+server%3A+Connection+refused or just google. https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=windows+postgresql+tcp+connenction+refused

Comment: Why do you think it would be on 5436?  That is a pretty unusual port to run PostgreSQL on.

Comment: I mentioned this port at the time of installation.