# PGadmin4 error ：Unable to connect to server：

Tags: docker, nestjs, pgadmin-4

I'm learning NestJS and I'm having some problems following the steps in the tutorial. As shown in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRmPC.png)

I used this command to create a container on Docker

```
docker run --name postgres-nest -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFgqh.png)

I tried the solution mentioned in this link
[text](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/57109494/unable-to-connect-to-server-pgadmin-4)

But after finding the address of this container and filling it into PGadmin again, I received a new error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti49v.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages in text form

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by reinstalled Docker.

After uninstalling Dokcer, I tried to check the occupancy of the locally mapped port 5432, and I found it was occupied by a program postgres.exe, so I closed the occupancy of the port by that program.

Reinstalled Docker and then followed the steps in the tutorial. Finally connected to the container in PGAdmin.

As a newbie I still don't understand the principle of it, but the goal was accomplished by mistake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).