# Timeout expired pgAdmin: "Unable to connect to server"

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, pgadmin

I am following the step-by-step instructions from *[Connect To a PostgreSQL Database Server](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/connect-to-postgresql-database/)* to create a simple server in [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#Database_administration). Please check the picture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I installed pgAdmin on my macOS machine, but I don't see why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 6):

It's an issue with AWS inbound rules, not pgAdmin. Follow [this guide](https://serverfault.com/a/1011181) to solve it. It works.

Comment: This is close to a link-only answer. Can you [summarise](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63510908/edit) here? (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 4):

In the file `pg_hba.conf` you have to change:

```
host    all             all             <your_ip/mask>          ident
```

to:

```
host    all             all             <your_ip/mask>          md5
```

`<your_ip/mask>` is your IP address where you are connecting from.

For example, `10.1.1.5/32`.

You have to add one if it doesn't exist yet.

I'm using [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS), so the file `pg_hba.conf` is located in `/var/lib/pgsql/data` for me.
If you don't know where the file is located on your OS you can use the search to find the file.

Comment: While I tried to open the file. It says "Could not open the file ....... You don't have the permission to open this file"

Comment: Check if you logged in with the same user as the owner of the file. If these are different users check what permissions for "other users" are configured on this file. On Linux, you can check it with `ls -l` command.

Comment: but when the IP I am connecting from changes, I always have to change it in the pg_hba.conf right? thats highly unpractical for me...

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is before saving go to advanced tab and in connection timeout give 100 or any bigger number and then save.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have tried with 100 and 500 but the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to "Security group rules" (under "Connectivity & security")
- Click the item "default" Security group
- Click "Actions" > "Edit inbound rules" > "Add rule"
- Select... Type: "All traffic", Source: "My IP", then click "Save rules"

Answer (score 3):

It was the same issue for me with a brand new [Debian 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_10_(Buster)) (Buster) installation.

#### File *pg_hba.conf*

```
#IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             all          md5

#IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             all          md5
```

#### File *postgresql.conf*

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

I restart the PostgreSQL service after with `sudo service postgresql restart`. Status is active and when I run

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
```

I get

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1071/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1071/postgres
```

In this example, I add all hosts. I know it's not a secure way, but it's still a test, and I will filter by IP addresses after.

Is there a particular configuration with `nftables` firewall to set up?

Comment: sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp; /etc/init.d/postgresql stop; /etc/init.d/postgresql start

Answer (score 3):

You may need to pass the port from the firewall.

Try this:

```
 sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ones that have only recently started to use SQL and are learning. You may have the same problem as me: you have only installed pgAdmin and not PostgreSQL.

After the PostgreSQL download and install it should be fixed and pgAdmin should be working for you.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows Users** Facing same issue I found this to be working.

1. Go To Run
2. services.msc
3. Make sure "postgresql-x64-16 - PostgreSQL Server 16" is running

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77811134/14384334

Answer (score 0):

First make sure, your [AWS RDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Relational_Database_Service) instance is set to be publicly accessible.

If the error persists, check these two things. Make sure the Route Table attached to your public subnet:

- has been set as main route table. To do this: go to [VPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_cloud) dashboard in AWS console >> Select "Route tables" option from the left link >> Select your route table >> From the "Actions" button click on "Set main route table" from the dropdown menu
- has the route for the Internet Gateway that you're using in your VPC. You can check this on the "Routes" tab in the lower pane of your route table.

Answer (score -1):

I was experiencing same problem, but I found that I forgot to install postgress first, so if you have not installed postgres then first go ahead download and install postgres,
[enter link description here][postgresql]

Answer (score -4):

Troubleshooting PostgreSQL Database Connection Issues

Answer:

If you are experiencing problems connecting to your PostgreSQL database, follow these steps to diagnose and resolve the issue.

1. Open a terminal and navigate to your PostgreSQL installation folder.
2. Access the SQL shell by running `psql` in the terminal and press Enter.
3. You will be prompted for various connection details, including the password for the `postgres` user. Note that the password input will be invisible.

   ```
   Server [localhost]:
   Database [postgres]:
   Port [7700]:
   Username [postgres]:
   Password for user postgres:
   ```
4. If you see the `psql (16.0)` line after entering the password, it indicates that the database name, username, and password are correct. In this case, the issue may lie with the configuration in pgAdmin 4.
5. Open pgAdmin 4, right-click on your server, and check if the port matches the one you used in the SQL shell. In the example, the port is set to "7700." Ensure that the port in pgAdmin 4 matches your SQL shell configuration.
6. If the port is different, update the port configuration in pgAdmin 4 to match the one in the SQL shell. Save the changes and attempt to reconnect.

Following these steps should help you troubleshoot and resolve PostgreSQL connection issues. Ensure that your connection details are consistent between the SQL shell and pgAdmin 4 configurations.

If you continue to experience problems, please provide more specific information about the issue for further assistance.

Comment: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)