# problem yugabyte works on the command prompt but not for PGAdmin

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4, yugabytedb

Sure, I can help you with that. Here is a sample email that you can send to the Yugabyte team:

Dear Yugabyte Team,

I am writing to you today because I am having an issue with Yugabyte not working on PGAdmin. I have attached a link to a Google Drive folder that contains the relevant information.

I have been able to successfully connect to Yugabyte using the command prompt, but when I try to connect using PGAdmin, I get the following error message:unable to connect to server : connection timeout expired[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laYjk.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTV10.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuKA1.png)

[i tried several times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKbhA.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76715168/postgresql-connection-timeout-issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532791/timeout-expired-pgadmin-unable-to-connect-to-server

Comment: Can you provide more info? What options were used in the other panels on the connection menu?