# "Connection timeout expired" error every time I try to connect to a server on pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, connection-timeout

I am trying to learn SQL, through a Udemy course, so If answers could be easy to follow, that would be appreciated.

I am trying to connect to Postgre SQL 15, but every time I try to connect, I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pieF.png)

It was working when I first downloaded it, but then after not using it for about two weeks, this is happening.

I am using a Dell laptop if that is relevant.

I am positive I am entering the correct password.

I looked at some other places for help (Stack overflow, and tried to look at pgAdmin documentation), but I am just not understanding it.

I'm expecting to be able to connect to the server, and make queries etc.

Comment: When using a different client tool, like psql, you do get a database connection?

Comment: I'm not sure what psql is, where can I see if I can connect to it?

Comment: psql is the standard SQL client for PostgreSQL. Works always, everywhere. But you can use any SQL client for PostgreSQL, just like pgAdmin. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: So do I just paste "psql -c '\x' -c 'SELECT * FROM foo;'" somewhere?

Comment: `somewhere` = your command line. And it should point to the location where you installed psql.

Comment: Are you sure that the rest of the connection parameters (host, username, port, etc) are correct? Is the database on the same server? If it's not, does it allow remote connections?

Answer (score 3):

On windows press windows key + 'R' together. A popup will open up there write
'services.msc' & click ok.

[image: services.msc]

After that look for 'postgresql-x64-16 - PostgreSQL Server 16' and start it by clicking on it. Now try again running postgres.

[image]

This method worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: YES. That's it. This solution will work specially if PostgreSQL used to work just fine.