# Connection timeout expired pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, localhost, pgadmin

Yesterday I installed postgreSQL and created a server on localhost, created a database and everything worked well, but today when I log into pgAdmin I encounter this problem. In that [state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532791/timeout-expired-pgadmin-unable-to-connect-to-server) talked about AWS, but after installing Postgres server worked well, although I did not register any AWS account, could this be somehow related? Sorry for such a simple question, I'm new in backend, and I only need a small db for my react app.

**Logs:**

```
ERROR   pgadmin:    Could not connect to server(#1) - 'PostgreSQL 16'.
Error: connection timeout expired
```