# PgAdmin- Postgres: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-12

Hi i want to use **PostgreSQL** for a school project and whenever i open the server in **Pg Admin** i got the same issue

when i first open Pg Admin i enter the password that i entered in the installation and when i click to server(1) it requires password for user "postgres" i use the same password but it tells me:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 1500? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 1500?
```

i don't know what does it really mean .. cause i'm new to databases and servers

- i reinstall all postgres & Pg admin : same issue
- i restart the server in services-postgres.. : same issue

I'm using PostgreSQL-12 and Pg Admin-4 in Windows-10

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msf4y.jpg)

please help !!
and thank you !

Comment: You need to modify Postgresql.conf and pghba.conf file. Refer https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/PostgreSQL/Install_PostgresQL_in_Ubuntu.md

Comment: it explain in ubuntu and i'm using windows  ... it is the same thing ?

Comment: Yes “Access PostgreSQL over network” is same for all operating systems

Comment: i did the config change and listen addresses "*"  but same erreur

Comment: Update pghba.conf and restart the database

Comment: okey i'm updating now thank you

Comment: i did the update and still showing the same error..  i really cant do anything for my project without the database

Comment: Another option "Enterprise DB" with graphical interface for installation and setup. https://www.guru99.com/download-install-postgresql.html

Comment: i followed the manual and reinstall and same error  ouf  :/

Comment: @Thirumal i change the port to 1500 and now it's working thank you !

Comment: This link here have suggestions solves for the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532399/unable-to-connect-to-server-for-postgres

Answer (score 7):

On windows:

- click on windows
- search for services
- scroll down to postgresql
- right-click on it and select properties
- click on the startup type dropdown button and select automatic
- then click start
- this will automatically run your postgresql

Comment: tanks @Banjoko Kazem

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem and as I edited the port to 5432 it worked. In my case, Postgres was running on 5433 and I changed it to 5432

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the problem is due to this:

`... accepting TCP/IP connections on port 1500`

Postgres runs by default on port 5432. Try changing the port setting to 5432.

Comment: in the postgres config  the port is by default 5432.  what if i change it to 1500 ?

Comment: yeeeees !!! i change the port to 1500 and now it's working  OMG i'm verry happy now :)

Comment: Why not leave it at the default port(5432) and change the port setting in the connection setting?  Most Postgres clients are going look for 5432 by default and you will need to change that to 1500 for each.

Comment: well i'm just gonna use it for now for my project and then i will change it for future work

Comment: Yeah well temporary fixes often turn into permanent ones. If it where me I would make the change now to save the hassle of undoing/maintaining it in the future.

Comment: hhh you're right Adrian ! but i have 3 project to finish in 5 days and as a beginner what really matter for now is the projects to work and then after configuration . but thank you tho for your advice !

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue is due to not starting a server, so you should start the server, one way to do it is to cd to `postgresql` `bin` and start it with `pg_ctl`, here is an example:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin"
pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data" start
```