# Can't connect to database PostgreSQL14. Can't start PostgreSQL on Windows services

Tags: postgresql

When I starting to connecting, I catch error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
            Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
    connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
            Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

PostgreSQL can't start on Windows services. (On my PC installed Win10)

This solution didn't help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27568135/17655569

Also I tried reinstall with this instruction (https://webkul.com/blog/postgresql-windows-installation-problem-running-post-install-step-installation-may-not-complete-correctly/), unfortunately, this method help before the first computer reboot

Maybe anybody occurred with the same problem?

Comment: Did you check the logfiles? Could you share it?

Comment: What is the error you get when you start Postgres? How do you start it?

Comment: 1) ВАЖНО: XX000: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\postgres.exe: подходящий исполняемый файл postgres не найден ПОЛОЖЕНИЕ: getInstallationPaths, postmaster.c:1495
I have Russian Windows 10. Here written that suitable file postgres didn't find.

Comment: Active code page: 1251
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I mean the postgresql logfiles, what does that tell you?

Comment: Oh, how can I get postgresql logfiles? Where there are exist?